# Oracle - using optional variable on dynamic SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the following scenario:

```
declare
  dinamicsql    varchar2(500);
  whereclause   varchar2(500);
  returnval     numeric;
  dinamicAuxVal numeric;
begin
  dinamicAuxVal := 2;
  dinamicsql    := 'select dummy from dual ' || whereclause;
  execute immediate dinamicsql
   into returnval
   using dinamicAuxVal;

  dbms_output.put_line(returnval);
end;
```

The 'whereclause' variable is a dynamic where clause that may not use the dinamicAuxVal variable. When the variable is not used in 'whereclause' I get the exception 'Bind Variable Error - ORA-01006'.

I understand why this happens, but is there any way around?

Comment: PLease show the two optional values for whereclause variable

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I don't have two optional values. I either have a reference like :dinamicAuxVal or I have none reference to the variable on "using" sentence.

Answer (score 0):

whereclause is not initialized! Try with:

```
whereclause := <whatever you want>;
dinamicsql    := 'select dummy from dual ' || whereclause;
```

See also: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01006.php

Use `if then` clause to initialize the variable dinamically. For example:

```
whereclause := '';
IF <you need a where clause> THEN
    whereclause := 'where xyz ... ';
END IF;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I know that 'whereclause' is not initialized, that's not my point. I need to be able to use or not (optionally) a variable in my 'whereclause',

Comment: This error: Bind Variable Error - ORA-01006 means initialize whereclause variable! Without this step Oracle can't execute concatenation. Use "if then else" clause to initialize it in a dynamic way, when you don't need it initialize it as an empty string whereclause := '';